# Does Express ammunition have any drawbacks compared to regular ammunition?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

I just bought some ammo for my Repeater, and as it wasn't expensive I bought all three different variants. As far as I can tell, the high velocity rounds give better range. But the Express ammunition seems to be simply a better version of the regular ammunition. It also doesn't seem to be that much more expensive.

Does Express ammunition have any drawbacks I missed? Or is it simply a superior version of regular ammunition, and there is no need to use regular ammo at all?

Answer (score 3):

As you have already stated high velocity give better range, but it also boosts your damage.

Express bullets only boost damage. Apart from the slightly higher price there are no drawbacks to Express ammunition.

[Source](https://www.gamerevolution.com/guides/450763-red-dead-redemption-2-ammo-craft)